# Javascript - Treat a var as an actual variable not a string

Tags: javascript

Say i have `self.option1ToCheck` to `self.option500ToCheck`

Instead of having 500 if statements to check whether those variables are 'undefined' I made a for loop. However am facing an issue with it treating the variable `title` as a string rather than the actual variable.

My code is below - the result I'm currently get is an undefined value for all `self.title`.

Is this even possible to do or am i going off tangent as

```
for (var p=1; p<500; p++) {
      var title = 'option' + p + 'ToCheck';
      if (self.title != undefined){
            myArray.push(self.title);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `bracket notation` for that purpose,

```
for (var p=1; p<500; p++) {
   var cache = self['option' + p + 'ToCheck'];
   if (cache !== undefined)
     myArray.push(cache);
}
```

Don't raise your eyebrows by looking at the variable definition inside for loop. It will be hoisted to its immediate lexical scope.

Comment: Bracket notation works - why is this down voted?

Comment: Because it war on SO!

Comment: just a guess: sometimes people downvote good answers for questions that are obviously duplicates.

Comment: Hahaha - war :-) 
So i accept my answer being a duplicate. Square brackets works. And just for my understanding, why is it square brackets fixes it - as in how is the dot being placed after the self - or is that just javascript magic i shoudl accept?